# How to run a command tool exe in C# web application?

Tags: c#, shell, web-applications, command-line-arguments, exe

I am using graphicmagic exe to execute a command using command prompt. I have added the graphicmagic exe in my application root folder. I want to execute this exe and pass the arguments through c#. How to do this? I have tried the below code:

Method: 1

```
Process proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
         FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\gm1.3.5\\gm",
         Arguments = "convert -define dpx:colorspace=rgb -define tiff:bits-per-sample=16 'D:\\Image\\FFv1\\dpx1\\1.dpx' 'D:\\Image\\FFv1\\tiff1\\1.tiff'",
         UseShellExecute = false,
         RedirectStandardOutput = true,
         CreateNoWindow = true
    }
}
```

Method: 2

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = @"D:\Executable\Projects\MMF\gm1.3.5\gm";
startInfo.Arguments = "convert -define dpx:colorspace=rgb -define tiff:bits-per-sample=16 \"D:\\Image\\FFv1\\dpx1\\1.dpx\" \"D:\\Image\\FFv1\\tiff1\\1.tiff\"";
proc.StartInfo = startInfo;
proc.Start();
```

But both of its not working. Please suggest a way to execute exe file and pass commands.

Comment: In what way are they not working? (Remember web apps run with limited privileges and access.)

Comment: Actually, I am using shell method to convert the image using this exe in vb.net, its converting. When I try to convert using C#, its not converting.

Comment: Is an exception thrown? Can you get any output from the process?

Comment: No exception. But the image is not converting in the path.

Comment: How to call exe in c# and pass arugments? like shell in vb.net

Comment: What other debugging have you done? (eg. Process Monitor)

Comment: This is the one I have tried. Is there any other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is working fine:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\Executable\Projects\MMF\gm1.3.5\gm.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "convert -define dpx:colorspace=rgb -define tiff:bits-per-sample=16 \"C:\\Documents and Settings\\software\\Desktop\\DPX_Test\\3.dpx\" \"C:\\TEMP_21May2015103216\\3.tiff\"";
p.Start();                
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be the privilege issue. 
Try to adjust the identity in your app pool to LocalSystem.